# How can I schedule in advance an update to a node, to occur at a given time?

Tags: nodes

In a situation where I know that a specific change to the content of a specific node will need to be made on a specific date and time, is there any way to automate that change so that I do not need to make the change manually specifically at that date and time, but rather can prepare it in advance?

The [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module allows for scheduling publishing and unpublishing nodes, and I am basically looking for some (hopefully lightweight) way to achieve a similar effect to the *content* of a node.

This is for Drupal 7 (though compatibility with the upcoming Drupal 8 is definitely a plus). Ideally it will also handle the components on [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) nodes (one of the things I want to be able to do is replace the list of options in a "select" component).

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a [Rules Schedule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules):

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

specifically this functionality: `Flexible scheduling system that allows scheduling any component / action.`

Comment: Okay... that looked promising at first, but unfortunately it has two problems. One, it seems quite heavy-weight for what essentially boils down to changing some text at a given time. Two, and this is something I completely forgot to mention in the question originally (sorry about that): it doesn't seem to handle webforms very nicely at all.

Comment: well, then it sounds like you will need a custom module

Comment: I'll see if anyone else can come up with a good suggestion. (A custom module is certainly an option, but it's definitely not my first option.) Still, have an upvote, because your answer clearly can be coaxed into doing what my question was asking for at the time of your answer.